# Laravel default Storage path change

Tags: laravel

I want to save image in main public folder using laravel file storeAs method. Is there anyway to change the path in using this code?

```
$path = $request->img->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');
```

I'm already try add new disks in filesystems.php to this

```
 'my' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path('app'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and store using this code

```
Storage::disk('my')->put('filename.jpg', $request->img);
```

but using above code it make new folder name 'filename.jpg' and save image inside that folder using random name. But I want to save that image name that 'filename.jpg'.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not in the documentation but if you check `storeAs` method implementation (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L80) you'll see that it is possible to pass an array of options as the third parameter. The `disk` key is used to set witch should be used. So your code would be:

```
$path = $request->img->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', ['disk' => 'my');
```

Bear in mind that if you are storing in a path that does not exists it is necessary to give the parent folder permission to create new directories.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very easily

```
$imageName = $request->file('image_name')->getClientOriginalName();
$directory = 'your/directory/path/';
$imageUrl = $directory . $imageName;
$productImage->move($directory, $imageName);
```